# Many to Many relationship MYSQL - Select data based on user input e.g. symptoms

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables

[image: Tables]

I want to get the ailments ordered by number of symptoms matches, and symptoms are entered by end user and are stored in a variable $searchSymptoms.

I tried following query with some alterations and got a very odd result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ailments.ailmentName,COUNT(symptoms.symptomID) AS count 
FROM ailments LEFT JOIN jnctn_ailments_symptoms ON ailments.ailmentID = jnctn_ailments_symptoms.FK_ailmentID 
LEFT JOIN symptoms ON ailments.ailmentID = jnctn_ailments_symptoms.FK_ailmentID 
GROUP BY ailments.ailmentName ORDER BY count DESC
```

Results:

[image: results]

I'll be obliged if any answer comes.

regards

Answer (score 0):

The query could be written as follows:

```
SELECT ailmentID, ailmentName, ailmentSymptomCount
FROM ailments a
     LEFT JOIN(
         SELECT FK_ailment_id, COUNT(FK_symptom_id) AS ailmentSymptomCount 
                FROM jnctn_ailments_symptoms GROUP BY FK_ailment_id
     ) temp
    ON a.ailmentID = temp.FK_ailment_id
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YDISLT24054)

Comment: thank you for answer, any idea where I could place the WHERE clause for symptoms. e.g. WHERE symptomName= $var

Comment: In that case, the sub-query participating in the LEFT JOIN would need to be modified. So, you'd have: `SELECT FK_ailment_id, COUNT(FK_symptom_id) AS ailmentSymptomCount FROM jnctn_ailments_symptoms jas INNER JOIN symptoms s ON jas.FK_symptom_id = s.symptomID AND symptomName = 'fever' GROUP BY FK_ailment_id`. Please note that the `ailmentSymptomCount` would now be totally dependent on the number of symptoms you provide manually to the query. Is that how it's required or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: first of all thank you for you time.
scenario is that I am taking symtoms from a search form, then look for thier IDs in symptom table, take those IDs and look for corresponding ailment IDs from Junction table and eventually use those corresponding ailment IDs to fetch corresponding ailment names.

in short I am looking to get ailment names against a symptom search, somewhat like Isabel symptom checker. but that is quite well programmed.

regards